# Why is my code is outputing thousands of times?

Tags: java

I am supposed to make this code output Day total and then the number of hours worked for that day. The code is currently displaying the day and the total. But it is displaying too many times for the program to even register. For instance, it asks to input a day, and I'll put in Monday. Then the number of hours worked, and I'll put 6. It will then output Monday 6.0 thousands of times. The expected output should be Day Total 6. What am I missing or is added to cause this?

```
// SuperMarket.java - This program creates a report that lists weekly hours worked 
// by employees of a supermarket. The report lists total hours for 
// each day of one week. 
// Input:  Interactive
// Output: Report. 

import java.util.Scanner;


public class SuperMarket
{
   public static void main(String args[]) 
   {
       // Declare variables.
      final String HEAD1 = "WEEKLY HOURS WORKED";
      final String DAY_FOOTER = "          Day Total ";  // Leading spaces are intentional.
      final String SENTINEL = "done";     // Named constant for sentinel value. 
      double hoursWorked = 0;             // Current record hours.
      String hoursWorkedString = "";      // String version of hours
      String dayOfWeek;       // Current record day of week.
      double hoursTotal = 0;           // Hours total for a day.
      String prevDay = "";             // Previous day of week.
      boolean done = false;            // loop control
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      // Print two blank lines.
      System.out.println(); 
      System.out.println(); 
      // Print heading.
      System.out.println(HEAD1);
      // Print two blank lines.
      System.out.println(); 
      System.out.println();

      // Read first record 
      System.out.println("Enter day of week or done to quit: ");
      dayOfWeek = input.nextLine(); 
      if(dayOfWeek.compareTo(SENTINEL) == 0)
          done = true;
      else
      {
         System.out.print("Enter hours worked: ");
         hoursWorkedString = input.nextLine();
         hoursWorked = Integer.parseInt(hoursWorkedString); 
         prevDay = dayOfWeek;
      }


      while(done == false)
      {  
        System.out.println(dayOfWeek + " " + hoursWorked);
        hoursTotal = 0;
        prevDay = hoursWorkedString;
      }
      System.out.println(dayOfWeek + " " + hoursWorked + hoursTotal);
  hoursTotal++;

         if(dayOfWeek.compareTo(SENTINEL) == 0)
         {
            hoursWorked = dayOfWeek.compareTo(SENTINEL);
            prevDay = dayOfWeek;
            done = true;
         }
        else
        done = false;


       // Include work done in the dayChange() method
  if(dayOfWeek.compareTo(SENTINEL) == 0)
  System.out.println(DAY_FOOTER + hoursTotal);

  System.exit(0);

   } // End of main() method.

} // End of SuperMarket class.
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Look at this while loop: `while(done == false) { ... }` - how do you expect it to complete? You never modify `done` within the loop.

Comment: Only thousand of times? I would have expected it to print ℵ0 times.

Comment: Also, instead of `while (done == false)`, you might try `while (!done)` since it's already a boolean.

Comment: I don't think anyone else here would admit to this, but I have made this kind of mistake. Usually because I was thinking of doing one thing then decided to write it a different way but neglected to remove the loop I no longer need.

Answer (score 3):

```
while(done == false)
      {  
        System.out.println(dayOfWeek + " " + hoursWorked);
        hoursTotal = 0;
        prevDay = hoursWorkedString;
      }
```

In this code block, you aren't changing `done` variable, so it is an infinite loop.